# Nested While Loop Runs Once More Than Expected

Tags: c++

I am new to C++ (have been using it for around 2 weeks), and right now I am trying to write a program that will roll a dice and give a random number between 1 and 6, then count how many rolls it takes to get a 6. After that, it will ask user if they want to continue with a positive and exit with 0.

If the input here is 0, then show the average rolls to get a 6 and the number of 6 occurrences that the average was based on, and all of this using `do-while` and/or `while` loops.

The problem is, whenever I press `0`, the program seems to run the inner loop one more time before exiting and showing the averages.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    float number_rolls, number_sixes;
    int x;
    number_rolls = 0; // store the number of rolls made
    number_sixes = 0; // store the number of sixes
    x = 0;

    srand(time(0));//initialise random num generator using time
    int roll = 0;//declare a variable to keep store the random number

    do
    {
        cout << "possitive to continue, 0 to exit" << endl;
        cin >> x;

        do
        {
            roll = rand() % 6 + 1; //generate a random number between 1 and 6
            number_rolls = number_rolls++; // add the rolls to a counter

            cout << roll << endl; // out put the roll values

        } while (roll != 6);

        number_sixes = number_sixes++; // adds the sixes to a counter

    } while (x != 0);
    
    cout << "average rolls to get a six: " << number_rolls / number_sixes << " you took; " << number_rolls << "rolls and got: " << number_sixes << " sixes" << endl;
```

Can somebody please help point me in the right direction?

Comment: This is not related to the loops, but  `number_sixes = number_sixes++;` is not the same as `number_sixes = number_sixes+1;` or `number_sixes++;` A postfix ++ returns the original value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reading the value of `x`, you can compare it to `0` and `break` out of the loop immediately:

```
do {
    cout << "possitive to continue, 0 to exit" << endl;
    cin >> x;

    // Add this check
    if (x == 0)
        break; // if this is reached, the inner `do-while` is not executed

    do {
        // ...
    } while (roll != 6);

    number_sixes = number_sixes++; // adds the sixes to a counter
} while (x != 0);
```

---

Now this makes the check in the outer `while` is unnecessary, and you can convert the `do-while` to a `while` loop with a `true` condition:

```
while (true) {
    cout << "possitive to continue, 0 to exit" << endl;
    cin >> x;
    if (x == 0)
        break; // if this is reached, the inner `do-while` is not executed
    do {
        // ...
    } while (roll != 6);

    number_sixes = number_sixes++; // adds the sixes to a counter
}
```

Comment: The fix works great, but perhaps you should explain how the outer do-while loop inputs `x` and then runs the inner loop once *before* checking if `x` is `0` or not, which explains why it runs one more time than expected.

Comment: he could also just move the code that inputs `x` to the end of the loop instead of the beginning.

Comment: @Barmar That would require duplicating that code to before the outer loop starts.

Comment: From the use of the `do-while` loop and the "continue" wording, it seems to me like the intention could well be for the innermost loop to always execute at least once, and the user has the option of repeating it. Your solution preserves the ability for the user to loop it zero times.

Comment: or maybe use a while directly instead of a do while

Comment: @NathanPierson Yes, that's possible. I think the OP can figure out how to do that if needed from the answer.